# oracle sql transcation block proper syntax?

Tags: sql, oracle

If there is a ParentTable table1 and child-table table2 and I want to make sure either both get created (in proper order!) or none get created, is this the correct syntax?

```
begin    
  insert into table1 values (seq.nextvalue, 'test') ;
  insert into table2 values (seq.currvalue, 'test3');
  commit;
end;
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO t1 SELECT a, b FROM dual` OR `INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (a, b)`  Your code kinda slips between the two :)

Comment: I'd put a field list into the INSERT statements - e.g. `INSERT INTO T1 (FIELDNAME_1, FIELDNAME_2) VALUES (seq.NEXTVALUE, 'test')`.  I like to offer the database the fewest number of chances possible to fold, spindle, mutilate, or misinterpret what I meant.

Comment: No need to use BEGIN/END if you have disabled autocommit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but must be like that

```
begin    
  insert into table1 values(seq.nextval, 'test') ;
  insert into table2 values(seq.currval, 'test3');
  commit;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about different values in your sequence assignment then fetch it into a variable before your insertion.
If any exceptions are raised it'll rollback the insertions, otherwise it'll commit them.

```
DECLARE
   v_seq_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT seq.nextval
     INTO v_seq_id
     FROM dual;
   --
   INSERT INTO table1
   VALUES (
      v_seq_id,
      'test'
   );
   --
   INSERT INTO table2
   VALUES (
      v_seq_id,
      'test3'
   );
   --
   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN others
   THEN
      <log_error>
      ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I'm not just worried about different seq values, but only first insert taking place and not the other - for whatever reason. I'm guessing that's where exception thing comes in. Btw, am I right in being worried about different seq values?

Comment: @progtick, it depends on whether you really need the sequence values to match (i.e. for a foreign key relationship). As for the inserts and one happening without the other, you are correct, the exception section would ensure that if there was an error in one of the inserts, a rollback would occur ensuring nothing was inserted into either table.

Comment: In the EXCEPTION block you might want to replace `<log_error>` with `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error - ' || SQLCODE || ' : ' || SQLERRM)`.

Comment: @BobJarvis, I was hoping the OP had their own custom error logging to insert there :-)